# how to parse Json object like an array in typescript . MAP inside MAP firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angular8

I want to parse `driverDocumentDetails` like an Array.

JSON is implemented from android (Java) HashMap data structure 
Angular Firestore MAP inside MAP

```
{ 
   "driverDocumentDetails":{ 
      "fhgfh":{ 
         "documentCategoryID":"fhgfh",
         "documentCategoryName":"Pan Card",
         "documentUploadedDateTime":null,
         "reasonForRejection":null,
         "uploaded":false,
         "uploadedDocumentURL":null,
         "verified":false
      },
      "bjhbh":{ 
         "documentCategoryID":"bjhbh",
         "documentCategoryName":"Driving License",
         "documentUploadedDateTime":null,
         "reasonForRejection":null,
         "uploaded":false,
         "uploadedDocumentURL":null,
         "verified":false
      },
      "hgvjh":{ 
         "documentCategoryID":"hgvjh",
         "documentCategoryName":"NOC",
         "documentUploadedDateTime":null,
         "reasonForRejection":null,
         "uploaded":false,
         "uploadedDocumentURL":null,
         "verified":false
      }
   },
   "driverID":"bhbjhbjhbj",
   "hgchg":[ 
      { 
         "bjnk":"jhbjhb",
         "fhfyhgf":"jjb"
      },
      { 
         "gfhg":"jgjuy",
         "gh":"guguj"
      }
   ]
}
```

```
onCustom(recordRow) {
    console.log("onCustom Driver docs data---->",recordRow);
    this.crudService.ReadDriverDocuments(recordRow.data.id).subscribe(data => {

    this.driverDocument = data.data();
    console.log('ReadDriverDocuments',this.driverDocument);
    });
  }
```

Comment: [Do the proper formating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Why your question contains unwanted commented code? Post it as a try:)

Comment: What is the output of `console.log('ReadDriverDocuments',this.driverDocument);`?

Comment: just simple declare one list: `arr = []; arr.push(obj);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` to get the keys and then map it into a new array:

```
var driverDocumentDetailsArray = Object.keys(this.driverDocument.driverDocumentDetails)
    .map(key => this.driverDocument.driverDocumentDetails[key]);
```

Or if it's available, just `Object.values`

```
var driverDocumentDetailsArray = Object.values(this.driverDocument.driverDocumentDetails);
```